# Can not insert data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android SQLite inserting and deleting from database. Initially I tried in a separate project which works fine but when I implemented the same in the project I am working on it does not work. Need your help. thank you.
Following is the code for the DB.

```
   public class DBStaffList {

    private static final String KEY_STAFFID = "StaffId";
    private static final String KEY_STAFFNAME = "StaffName";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "StaffList";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBStaffListHelper staffListHelper;
    private final Context staffListContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase staffListDatabase;

    private static class DBStaffListHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBStaffListHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_STAFFID
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_STAFFNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    public DBStaffList (Context c){
        staffListContext = c;
    }

    public DBStaffList open() throws SQLException{
        staffListHelper = new DBStaffListHelper(staffListContext);
        staffListDatabase = staffListHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;        
    }

    public void close(){
        staffListHelper.close();
    }

    public long createStaffEntry(String staffIdd, String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_STAFFID, staffIdd);
        cv.put(KEY_STAFFNAME, name);        
        return staffListDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);      
    }

    public String getStaffData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_STAFFID, KEY_STAFFNAME};
        Cursor c = staffListDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";

        int iStaffId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STAFFID);
        int iStaffName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STAFFNAME);


        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iStaffId) + " " + c.getString(iStaffName) + "\n";
        }


        return result;
    }

    public void deleteTable() throws SQLException{
        staffListDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    }
```

Accessing the code from a different class:

```
DBStaffList saveStaffList = new DBStaffList(IncidentsActivity.this);
                saveStaffList.open();
                saveStaffList.createStaffEntry("101", "Rao");
                saveStaffList.close();
```

Log cat:

```
  02-08 09:26:46.361: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8010): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-08 09:26:46.361: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8010): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-08 09:26:46.991: E/SQLiteLog(8010): (1) table StaffList has no column named StaffId
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010): Error inserting StaffId=101 StaffName=Rao
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaffList has no column named StaffId (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaffList(StaffId,StaffName) VALUES (?,?)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1108)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:681)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:589)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1573)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1445)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at com.dimensions.dimensionsapp.DBStaffList.createStaffEntry(DBStaffList.java:68)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at com.dimensions.dimensionsapp.IncidentsActivity.onClick(IncidentsActivity.java:282)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4262)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17421)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-08 09:26:47.031: E/SQLiteDatabase(8010):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when I did the same in a separate project it works absolutely fine. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such table exception because...

```
"CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_COSTCODE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_COSTCODENAME + "TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

should be

```
 "CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_COSTCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_COSTCODENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

space after `key_costcode` and `key_codename`.

Comment: That resolved my issues with table thanks for that. But I have another table creation which is named DBStaffList with same error.

Comment: @Rao did you uninstall app, remove the db and run the app again?

Comment: No I did not do that.

Comment: Do that, see if this still occurs. And btw, this time StaffId column is the problem, not the table creation

Comment: I uninstalled the app and re-installed it. it still gives me the same error in the logcat.

Comment: I changed the table name to StaffListTable and column to StaffIDDDD. Still it says "no such table = StaffListTable", error inserting...

Comment: browse your db for that column name, check if can verify the error. Drop tables and create again..you can use a different version number and onUpgrade

Comment: I changed the versionNumber and its working now. Thanks for your help.
If I want to get the version back to 1 how do I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate` has an error (see the answer from @user2450263) so the database has no tables. Fix the error, and then make sure that the onCreate es called again (if the database exits, onCreate wont be called). For making it happen,  change `DATABASE_VERSION` to `2`.

Comment: Changing the version worked for me. thanks for your help